# Magento2 Price including TAX/VAT renderer class

Tags: magento2, price, tax, vat, renderer

Can anyone let me know which class and method is responsible for rendering tax price in product listing page? pricing without tax coming from `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` and method `getProductPrice` but when I switch to other store which have tax/vat pricing, its not coming from there

Comment: you can refer this link **https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4572**

Answer (score 1):

I got answer i had some customization in my custom module and had method in helper class.